# how to return RESTFUL response from a JAX-WS WebService

Tags: web-services, rest, jax-ws

I have a JAX-WS WebService running and I want to add a RESTFUL method in it to return HTTP response, without writing a new service.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

JAX-WS is an API for SOAP Webservices, with are based on XML transmission of information, not some data over http - the REST way.

What is your services stack? Metro, axis2?

If you use CXF it provides you the possibility to serve both kinds.

Also you may join the two technologies in the same application.